# Display fixed number of rows on a tablix in SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report made in SQL Server Report Builder and I would like to show a fixed number of row per table, not per page.
I found out this expression =CEILING(RowNumber(Nothing)/25) and probe it on the row group, bit did not work.

[image]

In the image above, I want to fixed the number of rows where the <> is going to be populated with database data.

How can make this?

Answer (score 0):

In the Group properties add this as a Group on expression:
=CInt(Ceiling(RowNumber(nothing)/25)). Let me know if this works for you :)